# Retrieve nested object into array in es6 or lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, lodash

I am trying to extract nested objects of same keys into an array from array of objects.

Example:

There is an array as shown below:

```
[
 {
  id:1,
  model:'car',
  manufacturer:{
   id:1,
   name:'benz',
   year:2010
  }
 },
 {
  id:1,
  model:'car',
  manufacturer:{
   id:2,
   name:'benz',
   year:2012
  }
 },
 {
  id:2,
  model:'bus',
  manufacturer:{
   id:3,
   name:'volvo',
   year:2020
  }
 }
]
```

I need the result as shown below:

```
[
 {
   id:1,
   model:'car',
   manufacturer:[
    {
     id:1,
     name:'benz',
     year:2010
    },
    {
     id:2,
     name:'benz',
     year:2012
    }
   ]
 },
 {
  id:2,
  model:'bus',
  manufacturer:{
   id:3,
   name:'volvo',
   year:2020
  }
 }
]
```

How to achieve this? I tried all the possible ways using lodash but unable to get desired result. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using `Array.prototype.reduce`?

Comment: Tried but didn't worked

Comment: Post your code so we can help you identify where you went wrong.

Comment: @fubar I don't have any way to do it, so I am looking if any one can provide solution.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let data =[
 {
  id:1,
  model:'car',
  manufacturer:{
   id:1,
   name:'benz',
   year:2010
  }
 },
 {
  id:1,
  model:'car',
  manufacturer:{
   id:2,
   name:'benz',
   year:2012
  }
 },
 {
  id:2,
  model:'bus',
  manufacturer:{
   id:3,
   name:'volvo',
   year:2020
  }
 }
]   

   let temp=[];
    for(var  i=0;i<=data.length-1;i++){
      let pos = temp.findIndex(el=>el.id==data[i]['id']);
      if(pos == -1){
        temp.push(data[i]);
      }else{
       let obj = temp[pos]['manufacturer'];
       temp[pos]['manufacturer'] = Array.isArray(obj) ? [...obj,data[i]['manufacturer']] : [obj,data[i]['manufacturer']]
      }
    }

console.log(temp)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do with simple for loops

```
for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++)) {
// check required key matching
// append to new array
}
```

Comment: I downvoted, because your original response in no way answered the question. Your latest edit doesn't provide a comprehensive answer either.